# How to get actual image width/height from ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rl_root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:src="@drawable/image2" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_clickable_first"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#aa000000" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I want to make a small part of image in Imageview(myImage) clickable after getting coordinates. Its working fine for me.
Now I want to get the functionality of pinch zoom on this image. As I zoom in, clickable area along with the image will also zoom and accordingly.

My problem is that, I want to get height of image in ImageView (excluding black spaces in top and bottom. As ImageView is set to match parent, Image is showing in center of the screen in landscape mode). EveryTime I am getting height of imageview.

My code for getting height of image and imageview:

```
 int imagWidth = imageView.getWidth();
        int h = imageView.getHeight();


        int w = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int imagHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();

        Log.e("height", "Image height" + imagHeight + "\n" + "Imageview height" + h);
```

So as per calculation:
Image height= 882
Imageview height = 672

Comment: see `ImageView#getDrawable()` method

Comment: @pskink... yes I have tried

`int w = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
        int imagHeight = imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();`
Its not working

Comment: @NileshRathod, the post u have suggested isn't genuine . . . just check the first comment of  Jemshit Iskenderov on the answer

Comment: yes, it is working - it returns the size of the `Drawable` that is shown

Comment: @pskink : plz check my updated post
I ahve updated values which I am getting

Comment: and? the image you are using has the size of 882 x 672 pixels which is scaled by a current drawing `Matrix` and depends of your zoom level you are using

Comment: My image size is larger than Imageview..After I make it adjustviewbound true, its height should be changed...but accordingly i am not getting correct height of image.. @pskink

Comment: i have no idea what you really want to achieve: if you dont believe `getIntrinsic*` methods then try to cast your `Drawable` to `BitmapDrawable` and get the size of the `Bitmap` - get it by calling `BitmapDrawable#getBitmap()` method

Comment: hi @pskink, what if the image size is 100x100 and we're setting it into an imageView with height and width 50X50,then what will be the image's dimension by using the method u just suggested??

Comment: it will be 100x100 scaled by a current drawing `Matrix` - see `ImageView` documentation on how to get current drawing `Matrix`

Comment: image - 100x100  ,  imageView - 50x100 then??

Answer (score 3):

Work for me

```
    imgView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Ensure you call it only once :
                imgView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                // Here you can get the size :)
                width = imgView.getWidth();
                height = imgView.getHeight();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the height of an image in the image view you can simply do:

```
int width = imgView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = imgView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
```

This will return the 'intrinsic' values of height and width. (these values are the values of the image you are loading into the image view as is without any scaling. you can adjust these values to match any scaling that you may have applied) To adjust values for scaling (given you know its in landscape mode) the following should work :

```
int width = imgView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int height = imgView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();  
double scale = ((double)imgeView.getWidth())/width
int final_height = Math.toIntExact(Math.round(scale * height));
```

now final_height is the height of the displayed image.

Comment: I have tried this...not working...getting height and width of imageview..

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta ... can we see your code please ? as i have used the same functions before to get the height and width of images that i use in apps.

Comment: @PragyaMendiratta you do seem to be getting the height of the image as is. since the image height is different from the image view height. are you asking for the height of the displayed image ? just scale your image height by the current image scaling. ill edit my answer to match this

Answer (score 0):

Use these below code with **ViewTreeObserver**

```
int yourImageViewWidth , yourImageViewHeight;
ImageView y = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.scaled_image);
ViewTreeObserver vto = yourImageView.getViewTreeObserver();
vto.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
    public boolean onPreDraw() {
        yourImageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        yourImageViewHeight = yourImageView.getMeasuredHeight();
        yourImageViewWidth = yourImageView.getMeasuredWidth();
        Log.d("Height: " + yourImageViewHeight + " Width: " + yourImageViewWidth);
        return true;
    }
});
```